# Отправка запроса и обработка ответа

Tags: java, android

Формирую и отправляю запрос на сервер:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView tx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
    String url = "https://mail.ru/";
    try {
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);
     InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String bfr_st = null;
        while ((bfr_st = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(bfr_st);
        }
        tx.setText(bfr_st);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

В ответ мне приходит:

```
 main java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.maksim.myapplication/com.example.maksim.myapplication.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:316)
  at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
  at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:282)
  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:177)
  at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:271)
  at com.example.maksim.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам в ответ не приходит ничего, а исключение `NetworkOnMainThreadException`, которое Вы получаете, говорит о том, что Вы работаете с сетью в главном потоке, чего делать нельзя.

Ваш сетевой запрос можете выполнить, например, с помощью `AsyncTask`.

Comment: Лучше с помощью готовых библиотек, вроде okHTTP Retrofit и тп.